# datagridview1.columns[x] get id from combobox and then datagridview1.columns[x] bind to another field in table

Tags: c#, winforms

I have combobox1 and datagridview1.
combobox1 binds to table groupperson.

when user select item from combobx1 datagridview1 show id of selected item.
now I want `datagridview1.columns[10]` binds to another table and show name where id = combobox1 selected item id.

for example :

in combobox1 : user select friend where id = 5
when click button `datagridview.columns[10]` show 5

now I want `datagridview1.columns[10]` binds to another table and show name where id = 5 instead 5.